# ajax.beginform() not working asp.net .netFramework 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ajaxform

i have trouble with my code, ajax beginForm does not make reference with the controller event, i have all the library.
the view :

```
  @using MyWebsite.Models
    @model UsersCLS
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">My Web Site</h1>
    <section class="vh-100">
        <div class="container py-5 h-100">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/draw2.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Phone image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 offset-xl-1">
                    <form>
                        <!-- Email input -->
                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="email" id="form1Example13" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                            <label class="form-label" for="form1Example13">Email address</label>
                        </div>
    
                        <!-- Password input -->
                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="password" id="form1Example23" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                            <label class="form-label" for="form1Example23">Password</label>
                        </div>
    
                        <div>
                            <!-- Checkbox -->
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input"
                                       type="checkbox"
                                       value=""
                                       id="form1Example3"
                                       checked />
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="form1Example3"> Remember me </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#!">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
    
    
                        <!-- Submit button -->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign in</button>
    
                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                            Check in
                        </button>
    
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Login", null, new AjaxOptions
                                    {
                                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                                        OnSuccess = "Create",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "error"
                                    }))
                                    {
                                        <div>
                                            @Html.Label("Name")
                                            @Html.TextBox("name", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            @Html.Label("LastName")
                                            @Html.TextBox("lastName", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            @Html.Label("Email")
                                            @Html.TextBox("email", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            @Html.Label("UserName")
                                            @Html.TextBox("userName", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            @Html.Label("Password")
                                            @Html.Password("password", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes </button>
                                    }
                                    <div id="error">
    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

this is the Model:

```
public class UsersCLS
{
    [Display(Name ="Id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public string Add(UsersCLS usersCLS)
{
    string answer = "";
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        using (var bd = new MyWebsiteEntities())
        {
            int count = 0;
            using (var transc = new TransactionScope())
            {
                count = bd.Users.Where(p => p.UserName.Equals(usersCLS.userName)).Count();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    answer += "<ul class='list-group'>";
                    answer += "<li></li>";
                    answer += "</ul>";
                }
                else
                {
                    Users users = new Users();
                    users.UserName = usersCLS.userName;
                    SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
                    byte[] bypass = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(usersCLS.password);
                    byte[] bycryptoPass = sha.ComputeHash(bypass);
                    string cryptoPass = BitConverter.ToString(bycryptoPass).Replace("-", "");
                    users.Password = cryptoPass;
                    users.Name = usersCLS.name;
                    users.UserName = usersCLS.userName;
                    users.LastName = usersCLS.lastName;
                    users.Email = usersCLS.email;
                    users.Enabled = true;
                    bd.Users.Add(users);
                    answer = bd.SaveChanges().ToString();
                    if (answer == "0")
                    {
                        answer = "";
                    }
                    transc.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

}

But (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Login")
does not make reference with controller event Please help, sorry for my bad english have a nice Day and thank you.

Comment: **NB:** You're storing an unsalted hash of your users' passwords. That leaves your database open to a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack. You should be generating a unique salt per record, and combining it with the entered password before computing the hash. You should probably also be using a password stretching algorithm like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Comment: Some references: [Secure Password Authentication Explained Simply](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54164/Secure-Password-Authentication-Explained-Simply); [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right)